# Hecke Operator being a modular function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, modular-function

I have a question on http://www.personal.psu.edu/rcv4/567c10.pdf

I do not understand the proof of Theorem 10.6.  I get that from Theorem 10.5, we get that Tn(f) satisfies the weakly modular equation.  However, in the proof of Theorem 10.6, how c(m) and $\gamma{(m)}$ having similar support show Tnf is holomorphic everywhere including infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Being holomorphic in the upper half-plane follows from the fact that sum and product and composition of holomorphic functions are holomorphic.

Holomorphicity at infinity comes from the fact that Fourier series of $T_nf$ at infinity starts at 0. i.e. :
$$ T_nf = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n q^n $$
for some $a_n$'s and this (by definition) means that $f$ is holomorphic at infinity.